# Isolate methods among tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building tabs dynamically using jquery-tabs in a mvc view.
Each tab content is renedered by a partial view.
The partial view contains some javascript methods.
How can I make javascript methods specific to each tab?

Comment: how about iframe for each tab?

Comment: then i have to add the same sources again

Comment: Consider using Angular JS it is getting very popular these days